# Array Object is not Displaying in Nextjs Project using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, next.js

Hello I am a beginner trying to learn Nextjs. I created a component TeamCard that accepts the following imgSrc, altText, title, designation and socialProfile. But when i try to access the socialProfile object array to display it using map it is not displaying. Any idea what i did wrong?

[image: Data]

[image: team-section]

[image: team-card component]

Answer (score 4):

when you use `{` in your arrow function you need to have a `return` keyword explicitly .

Either change your map to

```
social.map((item) => { return ( ... ) });
```

or

```
social.map((item) => ());
```